# Has the congruence $x^3\equiv 84 \mod (139)$ more than one solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Has the congruence $x^3\equiv 84 \mod (139)$ more than one solution?

I could find $x=27$ by brute force. I could not find more solutions:

$x^{138}=(x^3)^{46}\equiv 1 \mod (139)$

Is this correct:

$x^3\equiv 1 \mod (139)$

If yes how should we continue to find more solutions?

Comment: It seems the solutions are $22, 27, 90$.

Comment: Do you know any group theory, esp. knowledge of structure of cyclic groups? If not, are you familiar with primitive roots?

Answer (score 2):

Since $139$ is prime, $(\mathbb Z/139\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic of order $138$. This is the key point. The solution below uses a generator of this group, also known as a primitive root mod $139$.

Since $3$ divides $138$, the equation $x^3\equiv 1 \bmod 139$ has exactly $3$ solutions. They are $1,h,h^2$, where $h=g^{46}$ and $g$ is a primitive root mod $139$.

Therefore, the equation $x^3\equiv 84 \bmod 139$ has three solutions: $27, 27h, 27h^2$.

For instance, the primitive root $g=2$ gives $h=96$ and the three solutions: $27, 90, 22$.

Comment: You should justiofy those claims, not simply state them. Likely the OP does not know these results or else they would not ask the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque, they all follow from the first line and the particular solution given by the OP

Comment: The OP says nothing about cyclic groups or their structure. It is not even clear that they have any knowledge of group theory.

Comment: @lhf 21. thanks for answer. Could you please give more details, for example what is magnitude of g, how would you find a primitive root like 27 without brute force?

Comment: @sirous, no efficient algorithms are known for finding primitive roots but typically there are small ones like $g=2$ here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Order_of_magnitude_of_primitive_roots

Answer (score 0):

This is my experiment on this question:

Consider equation $X=k.a+r$. This equation can have infinite solutions for given R  and a. But the number of solutions are limited when $X=x^n$ , in this case magnitude of R is also limited to certain values.

A-The goal is to find out  whether for a number like a  there exist primitive roots for (mod a)  for a certain power.To find a primitive root of congruence $x^n\equiv r \mod (a)$:

1- take the power n of two integer $b^n$ and $c^n$  such that:$b^n< a < c^n $.

2-Find differences $r_1=b^n-a$ and $r_2=c^n-a$.

3- Check $R=r_1$ and $R=r_2$ for primitive roots.

Example: for $a=139$, $n=3$, the closest numbers are $b=5$ and $c=6$ such that $5^3<139<6^3$ and we have:

$r_1=5^3-136=-14$

We check these:

$x^3\equiv -14 \ mod 139$ gives primitive roots (68, 76, 134). $x^3\equiv 14 \mod 139$ gives (63, 71, 144).

Now notice that $84=6\times 14$ and $R=84$ gives primitive roots (22, 27, 90). That is in congruence $x^n\equiv R \ mod (a)$ if you find a number like b such that $b^n<a$ and $r_1=b^n-a$,  if there is primitive roots for $r_1$ then there will also be primitive roots for $R =\ k\cdot|r_1| $.

For $r_2= 6^3-139=77$ we have primitive roots (20, 113, 145).

B- The sum of primitive roots is equal to a; for example $20+27+90=139\equiv 0 \mod (139)$.

C- The product of primitive roots is congruent $R \ mod (a)$ ; for example $22\times 27\times 90=53460\equiv 84 \ mod (139)$

D- If there exist a primite root then there exist $n-1$ other roots, or for power n there exist n roots.

E- If there exist primitive roots then there exist infinite cyclic roots which are generated by this formula:

$x=x_p+ m\cdot a$; $m∈\mathbb N$

For example for 139 ;

$ (22, 27, 90)$, gives $(22+139m), (27+139m), (90+139m) $

D- For n>3 mod (a)  minus or plus a primitive root $x_1$  gives another primitive root. Examples:

$x^4\equiv 80 \mod (139)$, gives $(62,77, 201, 340)$

$77= 139-62$, $(62+139=201)$and $201+139=340$

$x^5\equiv 7 \mod (139)$, gives $(51, 190, 329, 468, 607), 746, 885, . . .$

$51+139=190$, $329+139=468$, $468+139=607$

$x^6\equiv 6 \mod (139)$, gives $(11,45,56,83,94,122), 150, 184, . . .$

$11+139=122$

we may conclude that if n is even primitive roots make a cyclic group in addition to cyclic group of all roots.