# Under what conditions are all powers modulo a prime number distinct?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For a prime $p$ and a base number $b < p$, when are **all** $p - 1$ residues $b^0$, $b^1$, ..., $b^{p-2}$ distinct modulo $p$?

For instance, for $p=7$ and $b=3$, the sequence of powers is $1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5$, so we have $p - 1 = 6$ distinct values, but for $b=2$, the sequence of powers is $1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4$, so we only have $(p - 1)/ 2 = 3$ distinct values.

It's clear to me that the number of distinct residues divides $p-1$, but not how to predict what that divisor is from $b$ and $p$.

Comment: It's known as the primitive root. Searching this word may help.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no known simple general formula to compute the primitive roots mod $p$.

Comment: Such $b$ is called a primitive root mod $p$. An equivalent definition is that $p-1$ (or if $p$ is not necessary prime then $\phi(p)$) is the smallest natural number $m$ such that $b^m\equiv 1$(mod $p$). If $p$ is prime then it has a primitive root, actually even $\phi(p-1)$ of them. But finding them is in general difficult.

Comment: But usually, a quite small base does the job. That is the good news.

Comment: To test whether $b$ is a primitive root, it suffices to check that $b^{(p-1)/q} \not\equiv 1 \mod p$ for each prime factor $q$ of $p-1$.

Comment: @Joshua Frank, See my question 
 in :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891134/has-the-congruence-x3-equiv-84-mod-139-more-than-one-solution, it gives some idea.